# Comparing left principal ideals in a non commutative ring with unity

Tags: ring-theory, modules

If $R$ is a non commutative ring with unity.  Then $Ra, Rba$ and $Rab$ are left principal ideals for some $a,b\in R$.  What is the relationship between these left ideals?  For instance, which one of the following is correct?

$Rba\subseteq Ra$ or $Rba\subseteq Rb$

All I know is that $Ra=\{ra:r\in R\}$ and $Rab=\{rab:r\in R\}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$ba\in Ra$, therefore $Rba\subseteq Ra$ (it has to absorb on the left.)

There is no reason for $Rba\subseteq Rb$. You would have to show, in particular, that $ba\in Rb$. Without commutativity, this is not a sure thing.

For a counterexample, you can look at $R=\mathbb Z\langle x,y\rangle/(y^2, xy)$, and examine the left ideal $Ry$ and whether or not $xy$ is in it.